# Problema de conexion FTP en VS code

Tags: vscode, ftp

Quiero conectarme a un servidor para editar archivos en Visual Studio Code, al intentar acceder a los archivos por medio de FTP, en VisualStudio Code por medio de la extencion Remote FS, configure el archivo settings.json para poder establecer la conexion con las credenciales necesarias, pero me muestra dos mensajes de error, el 1er error es "421-Sorry, cleartext sessions and weak ciphers are not accepted on this server. 421 Please reconnect using TLS security mechanisms." y el 2do error es "421 Too many connections (8) from this IP", y no me muestra ningún archivo, no se que hacer exactamente porque es la primera vez que trabajo de esta manera, espero alguien pueda ayudarme

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario y añadir la info relevante
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta). Incluso si cierran la pregunta, puedes editarla para que sea correcta y la comunidad va a reabrirla para responderla.
La opción editar está justo bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas!